# multi Input search form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

First, I try to check if the two fields 'id' and 'flowid' in form are in the same row or not. If they are in the same row, bring all the data in the row into the view. If not the same, then return and display a message that your inputs don't match. I'm having issues with this. Please advise.

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('letters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id()->unique();
    $table->string('flowid');
    $table->string('id_number');
    $table->string('letter_type');
    $table->string('name_en');
    $table->string('name_ar');
    $table->string('nationality_en');
    $table->string('nationality_ar');
    $table->string('jobt_en');
    $table->string('jobt_ar');
    $table->string('to_en');
    $table->string('to_ar');
    $table->date('date_issue');
    $table->date('hdate');
    $table->date('salary_next');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('iban')->nullable();
    $table->string('endser')->nullable();
    $table->string('endser1')->nullable();
    $table->string('salary_b_l')->nullable();
    $table->string('housing_l')->nullable();
    $table->string('trans_l')->nullable();
    $table->string('mob_all_l')->nullable();
    $table->string('other_l')->nullable();
    $table->string('total_salary_l')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Model**

```
class Letter extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded=[];
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $flowid = $request->flowid;
    if ($id != "") {
        $letter = Letter::where('flowid', 'LIKE', '%' . $id . '%')->get();
        if (!empty($flowid)) {
            $letter->where('flowid', '=', $flowid);
        }

        $letter = Letter::findOrFail($letter());

        return view('layouts.verify', compact('letter'));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('letter.verfiy') }}" method="GET">
    {{-- @csrf --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">
            Certificate Code:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" 
                   placeholder="Type certificate Code">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="flowid">
            Flow Employee ID:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="flowid" 
                   placeholder="Type Flow ID">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">check</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::any('/verfiy', [LetterController::class, 'verify',])->name('letter.verfiy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
$id = $request->id;
$flowid = $request->flowid;
if (!empty($id) {
    $letter = Letter::find($id);
    if (!empty($flowid)) {
        if($letter->flowid === $flowid){
            return view('layouts.verify', compact('letter'));
        }
        
        return 'Error'; // return error or redirect
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks but still have some error

Exception Property [letter_type] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:C:\Xampp\htdocs\eltter\resources\views\layouts\verify.blade.php)

I think here the blade does receive value from table with column letter_type

Comment: @Ali did you reach it like `$letter->letter_type` or ..

Comment: in view request to fill all the letters table check  Migration in above we need to bring all row data

Comment: then you are using collection right? You should @foreach it https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: the result become but still the result come for one input id only it's mean when I use form for field of id only it's work the code don't check the flowid in same row or not

Answer (score 0):

> check if the two fields 'id' and 'flowid' in form are in the same row or not

I believe a basic where clause should do the job for you here because you are checking `id` **and** `flowid` in one row.

```
$letter = Letter::where('id', $id)->where('flowid', $flowId)->first();
if (! $letter) {
    return "Letter not found";
}

return $letter;
```